# How to use libraries in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I am wondering about the limitations of using libraries in code name one.  Specifically, I would like to use a specific http client library that uses nio but I am not sure if that will even work in code name one.  There is an http1 client and an http2 client here

https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces

Can the nio stuff actually be compiled into iOs? or does it have to be synchronous socket http client implementations?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work and you can't. [This article](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html) is from 2016 but it's still mostly accurate. The gist of it is that most of these APIs aren't essential and if we add all of them performance/size would balloon to huge numbers.

E.g. a Codename One application can weigh less than 3mb for iOS production builds with 32 and 64 bit support. Our closest competitors clock at 50mb for the same functionality with only 64bit support. This isn't just a matter of size, it's a matter of quality (QA), maintenance etc.

This also reduces portability as we have to test this on all ports including iOS, UWP, Web etc.

Having said that we're open to adding things and have added some features to the core since the publication of that article. But either way, you can't just use an arbitrary jar and need to use a [cn1lib](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html).

Comment: cool, thanks.  That makes sense.  Is there a library to talk http1?  Is there a library for http2? @Shai Almog

Comment: Talk in what way?
Codename One has builtin HTTP support. Notice that HTTP networking on device is very different from desktop communication. We go through the native APIs and they require HTTPS by default which also applies newer TLS restrictions and often even support newer features of HTTP seamlessly. Pretty much everything is built on top of that

Comment: sweetness!! that's what we need.  I am guessing then http1 or http2 depends on the platform and negotation with server which is fine for now.